# Combining two datasets visual studio 2015

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to simulate something similar to how access handles their queries. I have two datasets from two different databases. I'm trying to create tables that have a combination of the two datasets. I'm able to do this in access extremely easy but can not figure out how to do this in visual studio. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: This is not a tutorial site.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: I edited the OP since you seemed to take my question as a tutorial question instead of a legitimate question.

Comment: `Is it possible to do this?`  Yes.

Comment: do you know if it's simply through code or can you do it through the designer?

Answer (score 0):

DataTable.Merge Method will work, but I'm not sure how you are trying to implement this or what your end result is.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk68ew7b(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yeah, I've looked at this and haven't quite figured out how I could implement which is why I was curious on whether there was a way to do this in the designer.

Answer (score 0):

Just use SQL to combine them in your datasource.